# How to make a strong cup of milk tea without boiling it much?

Tags: tea

As it is known that boiling the tea for a quite some time extracts tannins. But, that is the only way I know of making strong tea.

Cup size: 150 ml.

I put 3/4 cup of milk and 1/4 cup of water in a vessel with 1/2 tbsp of tea and 1/2 tbsp of jaggery on a slow flame, and let it boil for some time.

What is other way to get a strong cup of milk tea?

Is there a way to get a strong cup of tea without boiling tea at all?

This is the tea I use:

http://www.tataglobalbeverages.com/brands/tea/tata-tea/premium

These leaves are totally crumbled.

Comment: Is using more tea (1 or 2 tbsp) but not boiling it long (3 to 5 minutes) an unacceptable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution which suits me:

I first boil the milk, water, and jaggery together in quantity mentioned in the question. After the mixture reaches boiling point, I switch off the gas stove and throw in 2 table spoons of tea. I close the lid of the vessel and let the it sit on the gas itself for 6 minutes.

After 6 minutes, I strain the tea and the result is a non woody strong hot tea.

I think it is important to let the covered vessel sit on the gas because otherwise the tea will cool off in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule for tea, milk tea or otherwise... You can make it "stronger" a few ways. Increase the amount of tea, increase the steep time, increase amount of tea or raise the temp.

I would suggest trying it in that order.

1. Increase the amount of tea. More leaves, means more stuff extracted.
2. Increase the steep time. This should work, as essentially you're allowing more time for the water/milk to extract the flavours from the leaves. However the potential downside is over-steeping, which could result in more of the bitter tannins tastes coming out of the leaves. Since Milk Tea has a large quantity of milk and usually is a stronger tea to balance, this might be what you're looking for.
3. Raise the temperature. This might result in more "flavours" coming out, but generally, they're not the flavours you want. Most of the pleasant flavours of tea dissolve at a lower temperature than the tannins. Again, as milk tea is generally a stronger drink, that may be what you want. But I'd try this last, as you could also lose the other flavours in the tea.

Also, not entirely clear from your question, but it appears that you're adding the tea to the cold liquid? I'd probably heat the milk/water to about 80-90C before adding the tea. If for no other reason, than making it more predictable/repeatable as to how long to steep for.

Comment: Point number three is not actually relevant to the question - since the tea is boiled, and water doesn't actually get hotter than boiling (or at least, you can't steep tea in it at that point).  The first two points are good, though :)

Comment: Not entirely true.... If you're talking about the actual "boiling point" of water that is technically true. The original question referenced a slow flame. Which depending on your stove can range anywhere from 85C to 95C (185°F – 205°F). Also with most most teas you typically steep it at a lower temperature 70C-90C. If you raise the temperature of the water.... light simmer to a light or medium boil or a rolling boil, you will in fact get a different flavour. I certainly wouldn't steep milk tea on a high rolling boil, if for no other reason than the fact the milk would explode all over.

Comment: Ah?  I saw it a bit ago in an answer - water temp shouldn't change from the lightest simmer to the deepest boil, the whole pot hovers at evaporating (difference is agitation, since extra heat -> steam) - just like ice-water is the same temp regardless of the ratio.  OP's slow flame could mean less agitation...and the water/milk combo might boil at a different temp, but *that* temp is consistent.  Also, boiled tea or milk tea has a *standard* cultural assumption that is maxed in time and temp, brewed to death - it is both rare and odd for a cooler temp to be used, not "typically".

Comment: The entire reason that you get a rolling boil is that more of the water is at the evaporating temperature.... Have you measured the temperature of a simmering pot? It's not at the boiling point.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a reduced syrup then use that as a base for milk tea drinks: place a large amount of tea in a pot on the stove, add water till covered and heat gently until it has reduced down to a strong syrup.  Store this syrup in the fridge.  When you make tea, heat the milk to the temp you wish to drink at and pour in the syrup, sugar to taste, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

you can make tea at very low temperatures but it will take more time there is something i learned froma homeless man in california, he put a tea bag, or other herbal leaves, into a glass bottle of water which he carried in his backpack, throughout the day the teas flavour was imparted into the water which became warm though the day. in the evening he had a strong tea which was luke warm, to drink.

so you could try steeping the tea overnight in just the water and then warming it over a low heat for as long as it takes to get to the strength you like. then add the milk at the end. warm milk obviously wouldnt be advisable becuase it may sour, so you would have to leave out the milk.

also i notice when making chai tea that if i put the tea and water in before the milk the tea seems stronger, i think the milk impedes the tea tannins from coming out, so you could try leaving the milk till the end. hope this helps.